# Water depths map layer

Tags: openstreetmap, bathymetry

Is there any water depths map layer available? I would like to have something like this:

[image]

I have tried satellite, but this is not so great to see depths:

```
var satelliteLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 19
  })
});
```

Here seems to be something about it, but links does not work: https://www.openseamap.org/index.php?id=bathymetrie&L=1

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many layers are available for european sea regions:

Quick overview here: https://portal.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/services/

- WMS: https://ows.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/wms
- WFS: https://ows.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/wfs
- WCS: https://ows.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/wcs
- WMTS: https://tiles.emodnet-bathymetry.eu

and if you want to access to the data indicated in your link, you can do it through this WMS layer https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/mapserv

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be something I was looking for. Now just need to figure out how to add it as a layer in OpenLayers with JavaScript

Comment: No need to figure it out, you have an OpenLayers example at https://portal.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/services/

Comment: Have you tried them? Their links for examples does not work. I have also tried on my map, but there are no layers visible, also no errors produced... Maybe I need to ask new question thou on StackOverflow

Comment: You could also use a DEM source which includes sea depth as well as land elevation, and style you own colors depending on the depth https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-tiles-forked-l2q16f?file=/main.js

Comment: @10101 they all work in Qgis so they should be working with JavaScript !